# É possível criar Web Service em SSIS?

Tags: web-service, integração, ssis

É possível **criar** um web service em SSIS?
Até onde sei só é possível chamar um web service no SSIS.

Comment: Até agora, nunca vi ninguém fazendo isto. Mesmo porque SSIS é uma ferramenta de ETL e não de transação de dados.

Answer (score -2):

até onde sei não, você precisa de algum serviço que esteja escutando e aguardando uma chamada, o que envolveria programação, além do que é disponível no SSIS.

abraços